# Buttons created on runtime how to set on clicklistener for each?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-button

I am creating buttons based on the array size given. My problem is how do I make an `onclicklistener` when a button is pressed all other buttons change their background colour.

Eg: 3 buttons are present. when `button1` is pressed Button 2 and 3 change their background colour.
here is my code:

```
for( j = 0; j < arrayName.length; j++) {
    //create the button
    final Button btn = new Button(this);

    //set all your button attributes, like text color,background color etc. here
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn.setText(arrayName[j]);
    btn.setId(j);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(ProductPage.this,btn.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //add the button to your linear layout
    buttonLayout.addView(btn);
}
```

Comment: You could put all of the buttons into a list. Then on each click event, you iterate through the list and set the background for each button except the one that was clicked.

Comment: I did try that. But It didn't work as expected

Comment: you differentiate with id in yor loop

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

implement common onclick listener

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    for(int i = 0 ; i < buttonLayout.getChildCount() ; i++){
        View buton = buttonLayout.getChildAt(i);
        buton.setBackground();
    }
}
```

Set same listener for all button

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayName.length; j++) {
            //create the button
            final Button btn = new Button(this);

            //set all your button attributes, like text color,background color etc. here
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btn.setText(arrayName[j]);
            btn.setId(j);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            //add the button to your linear layout
            buttonLayout.addView(btn);
        }
```

Comment: I need the id's of the other buttons to change the colour

Comment: You can get list of all child view id from buttonLayout.

Comment: @TooLow : Updated as per your query.